# How to avoid horizontal scroll on mobile web with responsive web design?

Tags: html, css

I've an adaptable web application. To avoid horizontal scroll I've written the following CSS code:

```
html {
    overflow-x: hidden; }
```

This works fine on desktop, but not on mobile. If I display the app on a mobile device, the app adapts fine. The problem is when I do scroll from right to left. The page moves a bit. I want the page to not move horizontally.

Edit:

The page doesn't scroll on all mobile devices. I've tried it on two devices with the same version of Android and it only scrolls on one of the devices.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Check all the paddings. If you add padding to something with width set to 100% it will go outside the parent.

Shown here
http://jsfiddle.net/wzZ3W/

Code

```
<div id="fillX">
    <div id="childXFill">
    </div>
</div>

#fillX
{
    background:red;
    width:100%;
    opacity:0.5;
}

#childXFill
{
    background:blue;
    width:100%;
    padding:10px;
    opacity:0.5;
}
```

Also check negative left and right margins on elements that span the page. E.g. http://jsfiddle.net/s7zrukj2/2/

Also, use a CSS Reset.

---

If you wan't to use `overflow: hidden` you should probably set it on the body element too. Like so

```
body, html { overflow-x:hidden; }
```

Although the fact that something is overflowing indicates an error in your responsive design and you should try and fix it instead to prevent something not being visible to a mobile user.

Answer (score 37):

You can put this in your console to outline all block/div. Then you can find the one which is outside of your container.

```
[].forEach.call($$("*"),function(a){a.style.outline="1px solid #"+(~~(Math.random()*(1<<24))).toString(16)})
```

Comment: This inspired me to use `* { outline: 1px red solid !important; visibility: visible !important }` and discovered the cause. Thanks!

Comment: Excellent script @BaptisteGillard! Helped by saving me quite a bit of time on the mobile version of a site.

Comment: Excellent solution!!

Comment: @gillytech Thanks for the great tip. In my case it was necessary to add `opacity: 100 !important` as well.

Answer (score 19):

If is not working for mobile you should use the following meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale = 1.0, 
maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

this will set the width to device width.

Comment: [Please please don't set `user-scalable=no`](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/80487/revisiting-user-scalable-no) unless you really do have a reason to prevent the user zooming (e.g. your entire page is an interactive widget that has its own zoom / pinch-gesture)

Comment: @user568458 I make little web apps, so I definitely don't want the user zooming. How many apps do you know of the allow you to pinch and zoom in? Practically none (within reason).

Comment: It also appears `user-scalable-no` does not work on Safari on iOS devices

Answer (score 4):

You will need to make sure the width of the parent container isn't wider than the mobile screen size

So best bet is to use % widths for everything and ensure no content has fixed with that would be bigger than a mobile screen size

Comment: The scroll doesn't happen in all mobiles. I've tried in two mobiles with the same version of Android and the result is not the same.

Comment: This is what solved it for me, using % widths. Thank you, Luke!

Comment: Same thing with me. I had a couple of places where the total width of fixed elements was greater than the screen size. I think I also had a problem when the percentages added up to more than 100%.

Answer (score 4):

If any of you using Boostrap and came across this question then here's the answer.

#### *for* Bootstrap Users

Wrap your `.row` with `.container` or `.container-fluid` and it will solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Set your mobile viewport on your html header

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale = 1.0,maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

Make sure your hide de overflow

```
  body, html { overflow-x:hidden; }
```

Comment: You shouldn't set `user-scalable=no` unless you know exactly what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to share how I solved my issue.  I tried everything including the overflow-x, adding a red border to all elements, etc.  Still was able to scroll right.

1st I started by deleting containers in "inspect element" until the scroll right was not possible. Then drilled into the div's that were the problem.  It was a hidden drop down div that was on "**visible: hidden" and display:block;**.  I fixed that by putting **"display:none"** and all is good now.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Dexter's Bootstrap comments with the the top answers for padding, Bootstrap users should also look at the various spacing utilities / classes.

Link below for the current documentation though you may need to look at the relevant documentation for your Bootstrap version.

Anything with a p- or px- can cause horizontal scrolling problems even if contained inside .row.

Sometimes a pl-  or pr- can solve a px- that creates a horizontal scroll bar. Or a px-2 works in place of a px-5.

[The classes are named using the format {property}{sides}-{size} for xs and {property}{sides}-{breakpoint}-{size} for sm, md, lg, and xl.](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/spacing/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm really a beginner but I wanted to share my experience you might find it helpful.So I was making a site with a buggy template and noticed that in the responsive view it had a white space that let you scroll to the right,I thought it would be fixed by changing body or html width and overflow.But really it was the container for the menu that popped up when you pressed the icon for it.In other word the transition for it was ''width ease in 1s'' but by doing that it reserved some blank space to the right when it was hidden.So I just changed the transition toggle from width to height although I don't really know if that was needed at all or I just should do it with ''diplay'', and it went away.Hope that was helpful!

//example//

```
.opened {
    display: block;
    height: 90%;
    transition: height 1s ease-in-out;
}

.closed {
    display: none;
    height: 0px;
    transition: height 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

//instead of ''width'' like it was before.//

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that when I zoom in and zoom out on mobile, the UI would not fully zoom back out to what it initially was. I found this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag#viewport_width_and_screen_width

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.86, minimum-scale=0.86">
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add the following tag to your html

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale = 1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).