# Horizontal Scroll Appeared on Mobile

Tags: css

First of all thanks to anyone who responds. I'm sure this is a no brainer for a CSS wizard but for me it's definitely not something I have experience with, hence the question.

On my website I've got all of a sudden a horizontal scroll appearing on mobile (which was NOT there before and no CSS was edited for that).

In addition to checking on my phone, I also check via an emulator@ http://mobiletest.me/ (seems like it's there on tablets too). Does anyone know how to fix this?

Not sure if it's some WP plugin or theme working weirdly with the newer version of WP, but basically here's the CSS file's contents (it's pretty big).

https://justpaste.it/8v9yy (should be easily searchable & readable). I wanted to put it here but there's not enough space.

Thanks!

Comment: Now that some answers have been provided, maybe post the relevant section(s) of code that caused the issue into the question.  As is, this question would not be very useful for someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**
After looking through and testing out the CSS, it looks like the website behaves how you want it to when you make the following changes:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) { /* do the same thing for (min-width: 480px) */
    .typology-section {
        /* this makes all the text fit in the view */
        width: 80%; 

        /* the ad is wide, so this cuts it off at a certain point so no need to scroll */
        overflow-x: hidden; 
    }
}
```

I found this out by using Firefox's dev tools to pick an element (ctrl+shift+c when you're in Inspect Element panel), namely the one going out of the view, clicking on it, and editing the CSS in that panel to find what was causing the problem.

**Original Answer**

I tried it out, and it looks like the ad at the top of the page is what's taking up a lot of horizontal room and forcing a horizontal scroll bar. Can you try and manipulate the ad with CSS? If so, I would do something like this:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 350px) { //350-400px is roughly the width of most phones
    .advertisement {
        max-width: 300px;
    }
}
```

This makes it so that when the screen is a certain width, a max width is applied to the ad.

By the way, if you're using Chrome, you can see the mobile view by opening Inspect Element (ctrl + shift + i) and then toggling the device toolbar (ctrl + shift + m). Just wanted to throw that in there to ease the amount of work in checking the mobile view!

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15086908/how-to-avoid-horizontal-scroll-on-mobile-web-with-responsive-web-design) (specifically answers by Jonathan Azulay and user3302919) may be a good place to look for potential problems. I'm still looking through the CSS you linked but it looks like the problem is related to .topology-ad (at least in this case).

Comment: Here's an update... For both of your websites, I found that the problem was fixed once I changed .typology-section {width:100%} to just 80%. Try that out!

Comment: Idk if these numbers will help you, but try CSS line #4635 for the 1st website and #4313 for the 2nd one. Specifically, under the **media queries for 480px and 320px**, create or change to `.typology-section { width: 80%; overflow-x: hidden;}` (thanks to Sleek Geek for that) for both websites. Although, it may cut off your ad.

Answer (score 0):

While there may be other issues causing that problem, such as elements extending beyond the body, you can solve the problem by hiding overflowing elements.

```
body, html {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

**Note:** If elements within the page are overflowing they will be cut off. So, you must ensure that they are not overflowing by doing something like below:

```
.innner-element {
max-width: 100%; /* Ensures that it doesn't extend beyond its parent */
}
```

Comment: One dirty way would be to do something like * { max-width: 100% } which tries to stop all elements from overlapping their parents. And, if you add !important to it, it becomes even more powerful.  However, when you need to overlap elements for design purposes, you must be specific.